# Difference between Database.QueryLocator() and Iterable in BatchApex?

Tags: batch

What is the difference between `Database.QueryLocator` and `Iterable` in Batch Apex?

Which one is best?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The biggest difference is probably that an Iterable can loop over aggregate queries and types which aren't even in the database. You could batch over letters in the alphabet, days in the last year, callout results, etc.

Another notable difference is the QueryLocator can return millions of rows for a batch, whereas the Iterable can only pull in the synchronous query limit.